# How can I create a new variable based on conditions in R

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to create a new variable based on some conditions.

My data looks like

```
a   b
1   NA
2   3
3   3
NA  2
NA  NA
```

What I want is a variable `c` such that

- when `a` is not `NA`, `b` is `NA`, `c = a`
- when `a` is `NA`, `b` is not `NA`, `c = b`
- when `a` is `NA`, `b` is `NA`, `c = NA`
- when `a` is not `NA`, `b` is not `NA`, and `a == b`, `c = a`
- when `a` is not `NA`, `b` is not `NA`, and `a != b`, `c = "multiple_values"`

How can I do this?

It seems like `ifelse()` can't do what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R you could use `within`.

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  c <- NA
  c[!is.na(a) & is.na(b)] <- a[!is.na(a) & is.na(b)]
  c[is.na(a) & !is.na(b)] <- b[is.na(a) & !is.na(b)]
  # # c[is.na(a) & is.na(b)] <- NA  # redundant
  c[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a == b] <- a[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a == b]
  c[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a != b] <- "multiple_values"
})

dat
#    a  b               c
# 1  1 NA               1
# 2  2  3 multiple_values
# 3  3  3               3
# 4 NA  2               2
# 5 NA NA            <NA>
```

*Data:* `dat <- data.frame(a=c(1:3, NA, NA), b=c(NA, 3, 3, 2, NA))`

Answer (score 5):

Except for one of the condition, i.e non-NA elements in both 'a', 'b', and they are not equal to each others, all other conditions are met with `coalesce`.  So, we can do a `case_when` to generate the "multiple_values" based on the last condition and all others by applying `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(c = case_when(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a != b ~ "multiple_values", 
               TRUE ~ as.character(coalesce(a, b))))
#   a  b               c
#1  1 NA               1
#2  2  3 multiple_values
#3  3  3               3
#4 NA  2               2
#5 NA NA            <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA), b = c(NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
 NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

`ifelse` can do what you want but it's just that there would be lot of nested statements

```
df$c <- with(df, ifelse(!is.na(a) & is.na(b), a, 
           ifelse(is.na(a) & !is.na(b), b, 
              ifelse(is.na(a) & is.na(b), NA, 
                ifelse(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a == b, a, "multiple_values")))))


df
#   a  b               c
#1  1 NA               1
#2  2  3 multiple_values
#3  3  3               3
#4 NA  2               2
#5 NA NA            <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R answer that uses `mapply` to loop through the pairs of values, a simple function that combines them and drops NAs, and uses `switch` to decide on the outcome.

```
df1$c <-
 mapply(function(x, y) {
                 z <- c(x, y)
                 z <- unique(z[!is.na(z)])
                 switch(length(z) + 1L, NA, z, "many")
        }, df1$a, df1$b)
```

which returns

```
df1
   a  b    c
1  1 NA    1
2  2  3 many
3  3  3    3
4 NA  2    2
5 NA NA <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, you can:

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA), b = c(NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                       NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
library(data.table)
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df1[, c:="NONE"]
df1[!is.na(a) & is.na(b), c:=a] 
df1[is.na(a) & !is.na(b), c:=b] 
df1[is.na(a) & is.na(b),  c:=NA] 
df1[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b,  c:=a] 
df1[!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a!=b,  c:="multiple values"]
```