# Conditionally assign values to two columns at once R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

**Problem:**

Is there a way to write a **single** command to assign different values to **two columns** of a row that meets **one condition**?

**Context:**

I have to conditionally assign a value to two columns: `Quantity` and `Price`. I want to do this using the `data.table` library in R.

My dataset looks like this:

```
> example
tariff  expenditure  
     1           50
     2           70
     3           50
```

Each tariff has different prices. Thus, a single expenditure can result in different consumption quantities.

Suppose the prices of tariffs 1, 2 and 3 are 10, 20 and 30 respectively. I want to do the following in a single expression:

1. If tariff is 1, then Consumption is `expenditure/10` and Price is `10`.
2. If tariff is 2, then Consumption is `expenditure/20` and price is `20`.
3. If tariff is 3, then Consumption is `expenditure/30` and Price is `30`.

In data.table, this can be done by slicing `example` as follows:

```
example[tariff == 1, c("Consumption", "Price") := list(expenditure / 10, 10)]
```

In the real dataset, `Consumption` and `Price` depend on the value of many other columns besides `tariff`. If I proceed as shown above, I will end up with about 100 different boolean slices. I'd much rather do this using `ifelse`.

The following code failed:

```
example[, c("Consumption", "Price") := ifelse(tariff == 1, list(expenditure/10, 10),
                                              ifelse(tariff == 2, list(expenditure/20, 20),
                                                     list(expenditure/30, 30)))]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In your first example, you wrapped the independent outcome variables in `list`. In your second example, with `ifelse` you failed to do this...

Comment: @lmo I did this because the `yes = ` argument is wrapped in `list`. I thought about wrapping everything inside `list` but I am confused by the outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: For `c(multiple values) := ...` the `...` must be a list of the same length as "multiple values". Here, given your structure, you may just want to use 2 lines. First the `ifelse` for price, then use a simple division for expenditure in second line. It sounds like your real example is more complicated. If what I suggest is possible, then that's what you should go for. If there are more variables involved, such that the current example does not represent the problem, please consider revising it or close this one and ask a new question. Also, you may be interested in `?switch`.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672622/how-can-i-create-a-new-variable-based-on-conditions-in-r/55676096#55676096) for a one example using `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clever way to do it (since your numbers are so simple in this case)!

```
#first make this a dataframe so tidyverse functions can interpret it
d <- as.data.frame(list(tariff = c(1, 2, 3), expenditure = c(50, 70, 50)))
#mutate can create new variables, and your transformation is the same in each condition
d %>% mutate("Consumption" = expenditure/(tariff*10), "Price" = 10*tariff)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to store your functions in a column of a transformation table (e.g. `tfn` here). Join this table with your dataset and apply the function to relevant column.

```
library(data.table)
#sample transformation
(tfn <- data.table(ID=LETTERS[1L:3L], 
    tariff=1L:3L, 
    consumpF=list(function(x) x/10, function(x) x/20, function(x) x/30), 
    priceF=list(function(x) (x-1)*10, function(x) x*10, function(x) x*20)))

#sample dataset
(ds <- data.table(ID=LETTERS[1L:3L], 
    tariff=1L:3L, 
    expenditure=seq(10, 30, 10)))

#join and apply function on values
ds[tfn, on=.(ID, tariff), `:=` (
    Consumption = mapply(function(f,x) f(x), consumpF, expenditure),
    Price = mapply(function(f,x) f(x), priceF, tariff)
)]
```